# reference jquery assembly in web.config

Tags: jquery, reference, web-config

Is it possible to put a reference to JQuery (or any other javascript file) in my webconfig, so that then I won't have to keep referencing in every page I create that uses it?

I can imagine if I ever upgrade the version etc. - it will be a bit of a hassle having to rename all these files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a  [Master Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx) for this.

Answer (score 1):

i am sure that their is no good way or best practice to do that in web.config

their is a little and good way to follow

put the reference in master page  [if you use ASPX viewengine]

put the reference in layout page [if you use razor viewengine]

putting the javascript from cdn is also better