# Can we add jQuery reference to web.config file instead of adding it to every asp.net page?

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery in web forms, and I am looking for any possible way to add jQuery reference to web.config so that I don't have to add it in every page.
Don't say Master Page please.
Because if we will use Master Page , the reference giving problem to aspx is repeated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137856/reference-jquery-assembly-in-web-config

Comment: Possible duplicate of [reference jquery assembly in web.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5137856/reference-jquery-assembly-in-web-config)

Answer (score 3):

Use [master page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx). add jquery reference there

Comment: Even for master page, I have to add a reference to my aspx page.... The problem is repeated again :(

Answer (score 2):

If you are using web page project you can use [Master Page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx). Master Page allows you to create a common layout for you web application pages. So that it allows you to create a common design pattern (like having common header menus and footer and having the common css and scripts). 
So that you can define all the scripts and style sheets which is common to all your web pages and include it in this master page.

You can then create individual content pages that contain the content you want to display. When users request the content pages, they merge with the master page to produce output that combines the layout of the master page with the content from the content page.(Content copied from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx):)

For more details about Master Page [Click here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx). It gives a detailed explanation about master page.

Comment: Even for master page, I have to add a reference to my aspx page.... The problem is repeated again :(